# Unity3D: разрешение отрисованной текстуры меньше разрешения оригинального файла

Tags: c#, unity3d, текстура, панорамы

Я пытаюсь вывести кубическую панораму. Сцена простая: камера внутри куба, состоящего из 6 кубов-сторон. Приложение загружает текстуру не из Assets или Resources, а из файловой системы компьютера. После чего программа выводит на грани куба соответствующие фрагменты текстуры с соответствующими mainTextureScales and mainTextureOffsets.

Панорама отрисовывается корректно. Но с катастрофической пикселизацией. Судя по всему, при рендеринге текстура была во много раз уменьшена.

У меня очень большой графический файл, состоящий из 6 картинок 2048x2048, склеенных в одну ленту. То есть полный размер картинки со всеми шестью текстурами - 12288x2048. Но после того, как я загружаю эту мега-текстуру в Texture2D, она показывает правильный размер: 12288x2048.

Если я считываю текстуры для граней куба не из одного файла 12288x2048, а из 6 отдельных файлов 2048x2048, разрешение становится значительно лучше.

Подскажите, как хранить текстуры кубической панорамы в одном, а не в 6 файлах, но при этом не терять разрешение при рендеринге?

Comment: С такими размерами — никак. Это гигантский объем инфы и Юнити максимум поддерживает 8192. А для мобилок так вообще лучше не выходить за 2048.... Можно поиграться с Format и Compression в настройках текстуры, но лучше не пытаться делать такого мутанта

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, получится ли, скачав большую картинку 12288x2048, разделить её на 6 отдельных текстур по 2048x2048? Или после загрузки большая текстура будет принудительно уменьшена до 2048x342 - и из неё уже не вытащишь 6  текстур по 2048x2048?

Comment: @Yana не получится

Comment: Получается, самый разумный вариант - хранить все 6 текстур отдельными картинками, но упаковывать их в архив типа ZIP...

Answer (score -2):

Можно от чего-нибудь подобного оттолкнуться:

```
bool SplitTextureRGBA32(byte[] mass,int w,int h,ref Texture2D[] SplitTex)
{
    int DIMENSION_RGBA32 = 4;
    int dim = mass.Length / DIMENSION_RGBA32;
    int countTex = dim / (w * h);
    if (dim % (w * h) != 0) return false;
    Texture2D tmpTex;
    SplitTex = new Texture2D[countTex];
    int dimTex = w * h * DIMENSION_RGBA32;
    byte[] mass2 = new byte[dimTex];
    for (int i = 0; i < SplitTex.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < mass2.Length; j++)
        {
            mass2[j] = mass[i* dimTex+j];
        }
        tmpTex = new Texture2D(w, h, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
        tmpTex.LoadRawTextureData(mass2);
        tmpTex.Apply();
        SplitTex[i] = tmpTex;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Подается массив байт, у `Texture2D` есть `GetRawTextureData`. То есть чтобы корректно загрузить, надо сначала текстуру сохранить в файл ввиде массива байтов полученного из `GetRawTextureData`.
Минус тут в том, что если размерность блоков на которые надо нарезать текстуру не все одинаковые, то есть допустим, текстура 512х512, нарезать на 512х255 не получиться, только на кратные, типо 2х128, 256х64 и т.д.(связано это с тем, что не понятно в ширине или в высоте есть не кратная размерность, массив байт все же)

p.s. Тип текстуры можно вынести в параметр, и через какой-нибудь Switch определить размерности(как `DIMENSION_RGBA32`) для каждого `TextureFormat`(ну или возможно у Unity есть какой-то инструмент для этого, не знаю). Либо определить функцию для каждого используемого типа текстуры.